# Can I calculate the sum of a calculated field in the same query?

Tags: postgresql, calculated-columns

I need to tally the total number of characters entered by students for all posts in a given Moodle course (as well as the total number of posts per student).  I started simple with a query that looks at just one student and one course at a time, and produces a new column with the character_length of the forum message. It works fine, but I have to tally the column manually and I'm only working with one student and course at a time. My query:

```
SELECT character_length(mdl_forum_posts.message) AS CHARS
FROM mdl_forum_posts, mdl_forum_discussions
WHERE mdl_forum_posts.userid = 1120
AND mdl_forum_posts.discussion = mdl_forum_discussions.id 
AND mdl_forum_discussions.course = 181
```

Can I:

a) tally the CHARS column and just get the total for all posts in a single query 
    or 
b) (even better) do this for a list of student/course combinations in one query?

Any information greatly appreciated. This table is postgres, though ultimately I have to generate this code in a query-builder that will work for other RDBMSs as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT character_length(string_agg(mdl_forum_posts.message)) AS CHARS
FROM mdl_forum_posts, mdl_forum_discussions
WHERE mdl_forum_posts.userid = 1120
AND mdl_forum_posts.discussion = mdl_forum_discussions.id 
AND mdl_forum_discussions.course = 181
GROUP BY mdl_forum_posts.message;
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply!  I tried this out.  It complained until I added at least a blank delimiter to the string_agg function.  Then it output the same as I had in my original query.  Maybe I am missing something?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT p.userid
      ,d.course
      ,SUM(character_length(p.message)) AS char_total
      ,COUNT(p.message) AS post_count
  FROM mdl_forum_posts p
  JOIN mdl_forum_discussions d ON (d.id = p.discussion)
  GROUP BY p.userid, d.course
  ORDER BY p.userid, d.course
  ;
```

Comment: Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* it addresses the question.  Without that, your answer has much less educational value - remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

```
select
    d.id, p.user_id,
    count(*) as total_posts,
    sum(character_length(p.message)) as chars
from
    mdl_forum_posts p
    inner join
    mdl_forum_discussions d on p.discussion = d.id
group by rollup (d.id, p.user_id)
```